# when insert data to database get error : value was either too large or too small for an int16 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik, dotnetnuke

i've got error " **value was either too large or too small for an int16**  " when insert data to database. i try to change to int32, but still error.

in the table, the data type of field  is "**int**", but in code I convert to **int16** because the variable **string**.

I've been looking for this error in google, or in the other question in stackoverflow, but i'm still not understand how to solve it this error.

Please, anybody here can explain why this error occur ?

Comment: In what DotNetNuke table are you trying to insert/update data?

Answer (score 0):

In the table change the datatype to Bigint
and in the C#, you also convert to bingint as like below

```
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@phnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt);
```

and also in SP, you change it to bigint as like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UR_SP
    (
    @phnumber bigint
    )
  AS
```

Hope if it solves your problem , kindly check the green tick and also upward the answer